# char is always changing using flex

Tags: c, visual-studio, char, flex-lexer, lex

I'm trying to learn how to use flex and I'm having some issues:

- each time when a token is found I want it to be store in a token I created, that part works just fine!
- the issue begins when it gets to the next token for example, if I've written:
  "a bcd" , it should identify it as a token a, and then as a token bcd, instead I'm getting the next:

  token a(at the first scan),
  and at the second scan I'm getting 2 tokens:
  token a
  token a bcd.

What am I missing? (When it recognize bcd, it just changes the token a to a bcd for some reason).

Comment: Code is text, please include it as such. Images cannot be copied to editors and cannot be searched. All in all create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It does not have to be your code verbatim. You can create a separate little example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: added the code as asked....

Comment: On buglet: the printfs have excess args without a format, atoi(yytext). Did you enable all warnings from your compiler?

Comment: @Jens , that is not the issue, I fixed it and yet problem stays the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was since yytext update itself, you need to copy it to a new char in order to work